# Converting separate Series for year, month, day to a single datetime Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have Pandas Series for year, months, and days:

```
year = [2016]
months = [6,7]
days = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

They come from same Dataframe, so the indices match up. For example, the index for 2016, 6, 1 match, and index for 7 and second 1 from days Series match.

How can I convert/combine this as a single Series as datetime?

Like,

```
date = [2016-06-01, 2016-06-03, ..., 2016-06-30, 2016-07-01]
```

Since days are all in one Series, I'm having trouble separating them by months.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear, but `to_datetime` can take a dataframe assuming the columns are appropriately named -> `pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'year': [2016, 2016], 'month': [6, 7], 'day': [1, 2]}))` / or subset an existing DataFrame: `pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])`

Comment: Okay, I slightly changed the format so that the Series are all same in length.
`year = [2016, 2016, ..., 2016]`
`month = [6, 6, 6, ..., 7, 7, 7]`
`day = [1, 3 ,...  30]`
And I can just do to_datetime with these Series, right?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'month': month, 'day': day}))` but it seems to me that since the series "come from same Dataframe"  that `pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])` or `pd.to_datetime(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].rename(columns={'col1':'year', 'col2':'month','col3':'day'}))` would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your data :

```py
years = [2016]
months = [6,7]
days = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

### Solution 1

We can do it this way :

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def date_cleanup(days, months, years):
    res = []
    last_day = 0
    cmp = 0
    for year in years:
        for month in months:
            for day in days:
                if day > last_day:
                    res.append(datetime(year, month, day))
                    cmp += 1
                    last_day = day
                else:
                    last_day = 0
                    days = days[cmp:]
                    break
    return pd.Series(res)
```

What we do here is a multiple loop on `years`, `months` and `days`.
When we get a day smaller than the precedent one, we remove all the already used elements from the list of `days` and we change the month thanks to the for loop.
You get the expected result :

```py
>>> date_cleanup(days, months, years)
0    2016-06-01
1    2016-06-03
2    2016-06-04
3    2016-06-05
4    2016-06-06
5    2016-06-07
6    2016-06-08
7    2016-06-09
8    2016-06-10
9    2016-06-11
10   2016-06-12
11   2016-06-29
12   2016-06-30
13   2016-07-01
14   2016-07-02
15   2016-07-03
16   2016-07-04
17   2016-07-05
18   2016-07-07
19   2016-07-12
20   2016-07-13
21   2016-07-14
22   2016-07-15
23   2016-07-16
24   2016-07-17
25   2016-07-18
26   2016-07-19
27   2016-07-20
28   2016-07-21
29   2016-07-22
30   2016-07-23
31   2016-07-24
32   2016-07-25
33   2016-07-26
34   2016-07-27
35   2016-07-28
36   2016-07-29
37   2016-07-30
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

### Solution 2

Thanks to the comment from @Vishnudev, I pushed the answer to get a more elegant solution on this problem based on the power of Pandas and Numpy :

```py
>>> years = [2006]
>>> months = [6, 7]
>>> days = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(days, columns=['day'])
```

We find the changing month using the `diff` method, and we use a boolean to mark when the diff is negative (from 30 to 1 for example).
Then we apply a `cumsum` on this column to match with the index of the list of `months`.

```py
>>> df['switch'] = np.where((df['day'].diff()>0) | (df['day'].diff().isna()), 0, 1)
>>> df['indice'] = df['switch'].cumsum()
>>> df['month'] = [months[i] for i in df['indice'].tolist()]
>>> df
  day   switch  indice  month
0   1   0       0       6
1   3   0       0       6
2   4   0       0       6
3   5   0       0       6
4   6   0       0       6
5   7   0       0       6
6   8   0       0       6
7   9   0       0       6
8   10  0       0       6
9   11  0       0       6
10  12  0       0       6
11  29  0       0       6
12  30  0       0       6
13  1   1       1       7
14  2   0       1       7
15  3   0       1       7
16  4   0       1       7
17  5   0       1       7
18  7   0       1       7
19  12  0       1       7
20  13  0       1       7
21  14  0       1       7
22  15  0       1       7
23  16  0       1       7
24  17  0       1       7
25  18  0       1       7
26  19  0       1       7
27  20  0       1       7
28  21  0       1       7
29  22  0       1       7
30  23  0       1       7
31  24  0       1       7
32  25  0       1       7
33  26  0       1       7
34  27  0       1       7
35  28  0       1       7
36  29  0       1       7
37  30  0       1       7
```

Now, we add the year from the `years` list and drop the unnecessary columns and we get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['year'] = years[0]
>>> df.drop(['switch', 'indice'], axis=1)
>>> df
    day month   year
0   1   6       2006
1   3   6       2006
2   4   6       2006
3   5   6       2006
4   6   6       2006
5   7   6       2006
6   8   6       2006
7   9   6       2006
8   10  6       2006
9   11  6       2006
10  12  6       2006
11  29  6       2006
12  30  6       2006
13  1   7       2006
14  2   7       2006
15  3   7       2006
16  4   7       2006
17  5   7       2006
18  7   7       2006
19  12  7       2006
20  13  7       2006
21  14  7       2006
22  15  7       2006
23  16  7       2006
24  17  7       2006
25  18  7       2006
26  19  7       2006
27  20  7       2006
28  21  7       2006
29  22  7       2006
30  23  7       2006
31  24  7       2006
32  25  7       2006
33  26  7       2006
34  27  7       2006
35  28  7       2006
36  29  7       2006
37  30  7       2006
```

### UPDATE

As specified in your comment @donnyan that you are able to provide a set of data with the same length, we can, as suggested by @HenryEcker and @Vishnudev, use the power of Pandas and directly use the @HenryEcker solution :

```py
pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'year': years, 'month': months, 'day': days})
```

Comment: Use the power of pandas if you are importing it.